# Design database to handle sending information to multiple users

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm working with `PHP` and I need to design a database for a web application where a registered user can send a single request to multiple other registered users, I also need to give that request a unique ID. 
I'm currently saving it in one table as follows

```
ID || sent_to || request details || more details
```

`ID` field is integer and Auto Incremented to count each time a request is sent by a user, thus giving each request a unique `ID`.

`sent_to` field is a varchar of 100 and and the values in it are the `IDs` of the receiver users comma separated (12,13,17,n)

My issue here is that from what I read online, I understood that I should create a separate row for each receiver instead of saving it like the `sent_to` but I feel like that will cause the table to become huge in the soon future and if I create a separate row for each receiver, the requests `ID` field will not relate to the number of requests sent by users over the application, since it'll increment more than once for each receiver of the same request while it should remain the same until a new request is sent by the same or another user. Can someone explain to me if I'm doing something wrong and why, please? Thanks!

Comment: Stop. See normalisation.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I was trying to keep everything in the same table, but I guess I'll have to create another table for the sent_to field alone, and keep making queries with Joins all the way, right?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks a lot! You're too kind =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a table which uses your id from the request table and has another field which is the user it's sent to.

table: request_user

Columns: request_id ( which is your foreign key )
    user_id ( which will also be a foreign key )

Your primary key will be both fields.

Comment: I suppose that's the only way, I didn't want to do this because the table might become very very large within months of the app being active. But I suppose that's the best way. Thanks a lot, I guess you've technically saved my life haha

Comment: Table size isn't an issue, it's a small table and even millions of rows won't cause huge problems.  The benefits are the design is better and later your sanity will thank you :)

Comment: I was just worried about performance issues later on, if it's not going to be an issue then I'll hop back and do the changes now. Thank you very much. By the way I believe there's a typo on your profile where it says 
"Find Art degree " Hope I helped hehe.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for that, we all make mistakes :)

Comment: Yes Sir! I'm a self taught programmer and I indeed know all about making mistakes, especially typos haha. Have a great day Sir.